# CMD command "if" with windows type

Tags: command-line

i want to make cmd file witch would take this command
systeminfo | findstr /I type:
and then save windows type (for ex. 32 bit). Then i want with IF help install winrar.
For ex.: if windows are 32bit, i want that winrar would install 32 bit, if windows are 64bit - winrar 64 bit.
How to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE` environment variable.

```
if "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "x86" (
   echo Do 32-bit installation here.
) else (
   echo Do 64-bit installation here.
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set /a "x64=1<<32>>32"
if %x64% == 0 echo 32 bit
if %x64% == 1 echo 64 bit
```

Have not really tested this on 64 bit system. Confirmation welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Ask for an input, 64 or 32 if unknown 32.

```
@echo off
echo.
echo 64
echo 32
echo IDK
echo.
set /p bit=
goto bit
else
exit
goto %bit%
:32
:IDK
start winrar32.exe
goto done
:64
start winrar64
goto done
:done
cls
echo. Installer Is running...
pause
```

Comment: Also If you had done any research you would have found the above code.